# Upload images and return filenames to DB

Tags: database, atk4, image-upload

I have a question: I need upload an image (in form) and add path to it (eg: /uploads/0/20131010_logo.png) to database (as value of image field), how can i do that? FileStore already configured

my form (field `previewIMG`):

```
$form = $this->add('Form',null,'addPostForm');
$form->setModel('Post', array('title','slug', 'previewIMG', 'category', 'date', 'body'));
$form->addSubmit('Добавить');
if($form->isSubmitted())
{
            $form->update();
            $form->js()->univ()->successMessage('Пост добавлен')->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model_Post

```
    $this->add('filestore/Field_Image', array(
        'name'=>'previewIMG',
        'use_model'=>'filestore/Model_Image'
    ));
```

filestore/Model_Image contains hook for thumb Expression [getThumbURLExpr](https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/blob/master/filestore/lib/Model/Image.php#L25) and 
filestore/Model_File (which is parent for filestore/Model_Image) contains hook for file (original image) [getURLExpr](https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/blob/master/filestore/lib/Model/File.php#L46)

In this case your model will have two extra fields $m['url'] (original image) and $m['thumb_url'] (thumb).

This is simplest way.

Comment: ok it works, but how can I get path for uploaded image on posts feed page?

Comment: i can't find these fields, my ways:<br />
$lister->getModel()->getField('previewIMG')
$lister->getModel()->getField('previewIMG')->getModel()->getURLExpr()
$lister->getModel()->getField('previewIMG')->getURLExpr()

Comment: You don't need to call "getURLExpr" manually, there is a hook for these two methods. Just use  $m['url']  and  $m['thumb_url'].